# Getting an Integer Input in a Range

Tags: python

I'm trying to take a raw input and detect whether it is in a range.
Here's my code.

```
def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    if next == int in range(50):
        how_much = int(next)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn how to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")
```

When I enter a number it gives me the else: "Man, learn how to type a number."
I guess the line that isn't working is "if next == int in range(50):
Could anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance!
Edit:
I'm a noob so that line was just me ballparking.
I thought it would check next to see if it was an integer in the range of numbers 0-50.

Comment: Please explain what you think `next == int in range(50)` will do.  Please **update** the question with a step-by-step explanation for this expression.  Perhaps you should try it at the `>>>` prompt to be sure of what it does.

Comment: Don't shadow the built-in function `next`.

Comment: "that line was just me ball parking".  Bad habit.  use the `>>>` prompt, please to confirm what the code does (or does not) do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since raw_input returns a string, you need to convert to an int first. Try replacing the line with this:

```
if int(next) in range(50):
```

Comment: This is not a good way to check if a number is between 0 and 50.

Comment: Ditto. There are much better ways to check this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "get an integer input in a range", you'll need two things:

1. Check if the input is an `int`
2. Check if it's in your range

**Check if the input is an `int`**

`try/except` will be perfect here:

```
n = raw_input('> ')
try:
    n = int(n)
except ValueError:
    dead() # or what you want
```

Why this is good?
Because if `n` is an `int` you'll have it convert it to an integer and if it's not an exception get raised and you can call your `dead()` funcion.

**Check if it's in your range**

If you get to this point it means that the exception before it was not raised and `n` was converted to an integer.

So you just need to do:

```
if 0 <= n <= 50:
    print 'You win'
else:
    print 'You lose'
```

---

Don't do:

```
if n in range(50):
    # ...
```

Beacuse it will build a list of 50 numbers for nothing.

**Note:** don't use `next` as a variable, beacuse it'll shadow the built-in [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next)

Answer (score 0):

The result of `raw_input()` will be a string, so first you need to check to see if `next` is all digits.  There are a few ways to do this, the easiest is to use the [`str.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) function:

```
next = raw_input("> ")
if next.isdigit():
    how_much = int(next)
else:
    dead("Man, learn how to type a number.")
```

Note that you do not need to check to see if the value for `next` is in the range from 0 to 50, since your next if statement already checks to see if the value is less than 50 and negative numbers will be excluded by `next.isdigit()`.

Comment: EAFP: `try: int(next) except ValueError: dead(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The test "next == int in range(50)" evaluates to "(next == int) and (int in range(50))" which is fairly meaningless and always equates to false.

Instead you could try

```
try:
    how_much = int(next)
    if not (0<=how_much<50):
       print 'Too greedy'
except ValueError:
    dead("Man, learn how to type a number.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using try .. except will allow you to make sure entered value is an int. `# raise` is a place holder for your handling a non-int contition:

```
try:
    next = int(raw_input("> "))
except ValueError:
    # raise

if not 0 <= next <= 50:
    print 'Too greedy'
```