# Learn python the hard way exercise 35 bug found

Tags: python, conditional-statements

referring to this code :
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex35.html

line number 12.

in the gold room you type 49 python condition wont work ?! (it jumps to else)
is this a bug in python ?!?! (btw, I am using version 2.7.8)

here is the actual scenario :

```
PS C:\Users\Sofia\python_projects> python.exe .\project.py
You are in a dark room.
There is a door to your right and left.
Which one do you take?
> left
There is a bear here.
The bear has a bunch of honey.
The fat bear is in front of another door.
How are you going to move the bear?
> taunt bear
The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now.
> open door
This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?
> 49
**Man, learn to type a number**. Good job!
```

while 49 should return :

```
if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
```

Comment: No, there is not a bug in Python to do with comparing numbers. You might think that someone would have noticed before now.

Comment: That "bug" was planted specifically by the author to make you think - read study drill 5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9437808/4193263). See anser [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9437855/4193263)

Answer (score 0):

The articles you gave me are old and speak about the int() function.

The real problem was not related to comparing numbers but to the logic of how he placed the if and else conditions.

this is the solution:

```
def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?"
    choice = raw_input("> ")
    how_much = int(choice)
    if how_much < 50:
    print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
    exit(0)
elif how_much >=50:
    dead("You greedy bastard!")
else:
    dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
```

sorry guys (am just a beginner....) but thanks alot for the help !